# Change the default wordpress@ email address

Tags: php, wordpress

By default WordPress emails, such as comment notifications, are sent from
WordPress

The Problem is when I click the Gmail or Aruba's reply button.
This will mail me to wordpress@mysite.com and not to user's mail.

what if I have to get the user's email that has compiled the form? 
How should I do?

Comment: Would you please check this screenshot http://screencast.com/t/X9aifU7dJn ?

Comment: Actually your answer is not suitable for this question. Try to understand the question. And the question is not about user's mail, it is about received mail from the user.

Comment: Would you please try https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/ plugin?

Comment: Actually this plugin for the sender only. i need admin mail. When the admin receive the new order mail, reply mail id will not get the user mail id, it will get the wordpress@domain.com. So this place i want to get the user mail id. Is there any possible to get it.